# Assembly immediate values

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly language and a bit confused about what is considered an "immediate value" in AT&T syntax. Specifically, I understand that "$" is used to either represent an immediate value or an address and "%" is used to represent registers, but then I come to accessing elements of "arrays":

```
movl mem_location(%ebx,%ecx,4), %eax
```

Why doen't this number 4 have "$" before it, isn't it an immediate value?

Thank you for your time

Comment: I think you misunderstand the meaning of *immediate value*. Immediate value means the value is included on the opcode. If it refers to memory (array) or registers, it is not immediate. Also *immediate value* is an assembly concept (it applies to a lot of architectures), not an AT&T syntax one.

Comment: @m0skit0 Aha, I see, thanks. You should make this an answer then, so I can do something with it other than look at it :P

Comment: The `4` in there is not considered an immediate, it's the `scale  factor` of the effective address format.

Comment: @Jester I see, I thought it actually took a value, didn't realize it is a separate case

Comment: `$` is mainly there to disambiguate memory references and addresses. `movl $x, %eax` (load immediate) and `movl x, %eax` (load from memory) are both meaningful. For scale factors (and displacement), there is no such ambiguity and no need for `$`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the meaning of immediate value. *Immediate value* means the value is included on the opcode. If it refers to memory (array) or registers, it is not immediate. As Jester points out, the `4` is actually a scale factor for memory addressing. This is not considered an *immediate value*.

An example of immediate value would be something like `mov eax, 123`.

Also note that *immediate value* is an assembly concept (it applies to a lot of architectures), not something specific to AT&T syntax.